# How do I prove that $|z|^t$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Define $f(z)=|z|^t$ for every $(z,t)\in(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})\times I$

How do I prove that $f$ is continuous?

Here's what I tried.

Fix $(z,t)$ in the domain and $\epsilon > 0$

Since $w\mapsto |w|^t$ is continuous for a fixed $t$, there is an open neighborhood $N$ of $z$ such that $\forall x\in N, | |w|^t - |z|^t | < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$.

Then, I tried to find an open neighborhood $M$ of $t$ so that for all $s\in M$ and $w\in N$, $||w|^s - |w|^t| < \epsilon/4$.

I think there must be some arguments using compactness, but I don't know where it should be applied.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|z|^t =e^{t\ln |z|}$$ and use the fact that product and superposition of continuous functions is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

$|z|$ is continuous, and we know a finite product at least of continuous functions is continuous... so we know $|z|^t$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The map $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\to (0,\infty)$, $z\mapsto|z|$ is continuous. The map $(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$, $x\mapsto \ln x$ is continuous. Multiplication $(x,t)\mapsto xt$ is continuous. exponentiation $x\mapsto e^x$ is continuous. Your map is hence the compüosition of continuous functions.